# SQL ORACLE - Extract data with some properties added in the last 180 days

Tags: sql, oracle

The table `SELL_TABLE` has these columns:

- LEGACY_ID
- PRODUCT_ID
- CUSTOMER_ID
- DATE
- SOLD

I have to extract all the rows ordered by `CUSTOMER_ID` where `SOLD`is `> 1` and inserted in the last 180 days.

The `DATE` column is defined as `VARCHAR`, so I need to transform its content to a datetime first.

How can I do that?

This is how I wrote the query:

```
    select CUSTOMER_ID as Customer, PRODUCT_ID as Product
    from SELL_TABLE 
    where SOLD > 0 and DATE >= DATEADD(day, -180, getdate())
    group by CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_ID
    order by CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Comment: Are the dates stored in a fixed format? If so, which one?

Comment: @Aleksej Yes -> 20160208 (Y,M,D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need a `where` condition with [`to_date`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/TO_DATE.htm#SQLRF06132) and [`sysdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/SYSDATE.htm#SQLRF06124) like the following:

```
where to_date(yourDateColumn, 'yyyymmdd') >= trunc(sysdate) - 180
  and ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> TO_DATE

function to convert your varchar column to Date type.

Also, you can replace the

> DATEADD

function with simple action:

```
trunc(sysdate) >= trunc (sysdate - 180)
```